Are there any advantages to using potassium ion over lithium ion batteries?
Are there any advantages to using potassium ion batteries over lithium ion batteries? What properties make an alkaline metal an ideal alkaline-ion battery?

Potassium is a lot heavier per charge / electrochemical energy it can carry, and more pyrophoric.

A few possible advantages I can think of:

Potassium is more abundant, as it is one if the most common elements in Earth's crust. This likely makes it less costly.

Lithium, because of its small ion size, tends to form ion pairs in the non-aqueous solvents that are used for electrolytes. Potassium ions are less prone to ion pairing and so offer better electrolyte conductivity.

Both potassium and lithium intercalate well with graphite, which is an advantage of both these elements over sodium, which intercalates only poorly (see Wikipedia). This enables the use of graphite intercalation for electrodes.



Of course, there are also disadvantages, such as being a bit heavier (though by the time other components of a cell are included, not so much. And for laughs: K is radioactive (but not much).

@DrMoishePippik "K is rafioactive". Well, so am I (at least from C-14). So we're even.

@OscarLanzi, but consider all the K in our bodies! And we're emitting Ar. What I find odd is that 232Th, half-life of 1.405×10^10 y, is no longer used in gas mantles due to radioactivity,  but bananas, containing .01% 40K, with half-life 1.248×10^9 y, is safe to eat. ;-)
